# Bad Idea to partition the drive the current os is on?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am wanting to extend my windows partition to occupy some unallocated space. When I use gparted in ubuntu it says there is something wrong with the file system and refuses to work the operation. But when I boot into the windows os that is on the partition I am wanting to change it will do it fine. Would it be a bad idea to use windows to partition the partition it is currently running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all, I have extended and shrunk from Windows just fine!

I am a bit concerned that Gparted is having issues though... Possibly make sure you are using the latest version and/or do a can of the hard drive to make sure there are not any other errors.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It is the only gparted I have that says that. The one in opensuse and fedora don't report any errors. I don't want to boot into them though because I am already in windows. Even though it will shift the os to the left it will still work?

Comment: Well, I ran a disk check in windows and the error went away in ubuntu so I decided to go ahead and partition from there. I did it, it said all operations completed successfully and I rebooted into my 7 repair disk like I normally have to do when shifting partitions so I can recover the boot files. Did that, went fine and all, but when I rebooted it said autochk program not found skipping autocheck, it bluescreened for a half second and restarted. Now i am going to attempt a diskcheck from within vista.

Comment: I don't know why you didn't extend from Windows - it is much safer

Comment: Well then. I was unaware, I normally do my partitioning with gparted in ubuntu and everything has worked fine so far. I just posted another question about this problem. The diskcheck in vista didn't report any problems.

Comment: I have tried to answer your other question... not very well :/ but hopefully it will put you on the right track.